# Get overlapping datetimes from pandas dataframe, considering other field

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe as follows

```
df_sample = pd.DataFrame({
        'machine': [1, 1, 1, 2],
        'ts_start': ["2022-01-01 20:00:00", "2022-01-01 20:30:00", "2022-01-02 20:30:00", "2022-01-01 19:00:00"],
        'ts_end': ["2022-01-01 21:00:00", "2022-01-01 21:30:00", "2022-01-02 20:35:00", "2022-01-01 23:00:00"]
})
```

I want to check which of these [ts_start, ts_end] intervals are overlapped, for the same machine. I have seen some questions about finding overlaps, but couldn't find that grouped by another column, in my case considering the overlaps for each machine separately.

I tried using [Piso](https://piso.readthedocs.io/) which seems very interesting.

```
df_sample['ts_start'] = pd.to_datetime(df_sample['ts_start'])
df_sample['ts_end'] = pd.to_datetime(df_sample['ts_end'])

ii = pd.IntervalIndex.from_arrays(df_sample["ts_start"], df_sample["ts_end"])
df_sample["isOverlap"] = piso.adjacency_matrix(ii).any(axis=1).astype(int).values
```

I obtain something like this:

```
machine    ts_start             ts_end             isOverlap
0    1 2022-01-01 20:00:00 2022-01-01 21:00:00          1
1    1 2022-01-01 20:30:00 2022-01-01 21:30:00          1
2    1 2022-01-02 20:30:00 2022-01-02 20:35:00          0
3    2 2022-01-01 19:00:00 2022-01-01 23:00:00          1
```

However, it is considering all machines at the same time. Is there a way (using piso or not) to get the overlapping moments, for each machine, in a single dataframe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[piso](https://piso.readthedocs.io) can indeed be used.  It'll run fast on large datasets, and not be limited to assumptions on sampling rate of times.  Modify your piso example to wrap the last two lines in a function:

```
def make_overlaps(df):
    ii = pd.IntervalIndex.from_arrays(df["ts_start"], df["ts_end"])
    df["isOverlap"] = piso.adjacency_matrix(ii).any(axis=1).astype(int).values
    return df
```

Then group `df_sample` on the machine column, and apply:

```
 df_sample.groupby("machine").apply(make_overlaps)
```

This will give you:

```
   machine            ts_start              ts_end  isOverlap
0        1 2022-01-01 20:00:00 2022-01-01 21:00:00          1
1        1 2022-01-01 20:30:00 2022-01-01 21:30:00          1
2        1 2022-01-02 20:30:00 2022-01-02 20:35:00          0
3        2 2022-01-01 19:00:00 2022-01-01 23:00:00          0
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way to do what your question asks:

```py
import pandas as pd
df_sample = pd.DataFrame({
        'machine': [1, 1, 1, 2],
        'ts_start': ["2022-01-01 20:00:00", "2022-01-01 20:30:00", "2022-01-02 20:30:00", "2022-01-01 19:00:00"],
        'ts_end': ["2022-01-01 21:00:00", "2022-01-01 21:30:00", "2022-01-02 20:35:00", "2022-01-01 23:00:00"]
})
df_sample = df_sample.sort_values(['machine', 'ts_start', 'ts_end'])
print(df_sample)
def foo(x):
    if len(x.index) > 1:
        iPrev, reachOfPrev = x.index[0], x.loc[x.index[0], 'ts_end'] if len(x.index) else None
        x.loc[iPrev, 'isOverlap'] = 0
        for i in x.index[1:]:
            if x.loc[i,'ts_start'] < reachOfPrev:
                x.loc[iPrev, 'isOverlap'] = 1
                x.loc[i, 'isOverlap'] = 1
            else:
                x.loc[i, 'isOverlap'] = 0
            if x.loc[i, 'ts_end'] > reachOfPrev:
                iPrev, reachOfPrev = i, x.loc[i, 'ts_end']
    else:
        x['isOverlap'] = 0
    x.isOverlap = x.isOverlap.astype(int)
    return x
    
df_sample = df_sample.groupby('machine').apply(foo)
print(df_sample)
```

Input:

```
   machine             ts_start               ts_end
0        1  2022-01-01 20:00:00  2022-01-01 21:00:00
1        1  2022-01-01 20:30:00  2022-01-01 21:30:00
2        1  2022-01-02 20:30:00  2022-01-02 20:35:00
3        2  2022-01-01 19:00:00  2022-01-01 23:00:00
```

Output:

```
   machine             ts_start               ts_end  isOverlap
0        1  2022-01-01 20:00:00  2022-01-01 21:00:00          1
1        1  2022-01-01 20:30:00  2022-01-01 21:30:00          1
2        1  2022-01-02 20:30:00  2022-01-02 20:35:00          0
3        2  2022-01-01 19:00:00  2022-01-01 23:00:00          0
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the overlap is only checked up by minutes, you could try:

```py
#create date ranges by minute frequency
df_sample["times"] = df_sample.apply(lambda row: pd.date_range(row["ts_start"], row["ts_end"], freq="1min"), axis=1)

#explode to get one row per minute
df_sample = df_sample.explode("times")

#check if times overlap by looking for duplicates
df_sample["isOverlap"] = df_sample[["machine","times"]].duplicated(keep=False)

#groupby to get back original data structure
output = df_sample.drop("times", axis=1).groupby(["machine","ts_start","ts_end"]).any().astype(int).reset_index()

>>> output
   machine             ts_start               ts_end  isOverlap
0        1  2022-01-01 20:00:00  2022-01-01 21:00:00          1
1        1  2022-01-01 20:30:00  2022-01-01 21:30:00          1
2        1  2022-01-02 20:30:00  2022-01-02 20:35:00          0
3        2  2022-01-01 19:00:00  2022-01-01 23:00:00          0
```